# how to give default date range in air-datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, air, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want when calender.html loads the minRange and maxRange be auto-selected

calender.html

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include English language -->
    <script src="datepicker.en.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var date = new Date();
    var currentMonthStartDay = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), 1);
    var currentMonthLastDay = new Date(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth() + 1, 0);


        $('#my-element').data('datepicker').minRange = currentMonthStartDay;
        $('#my-element').data('datepicker').maxRange = currentMonthLastDay;


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- <input type='text' class="datepicker-here" data-position="right top" /> -->
    <div class="datepicker-here" id='my-element' data-language='en' data-range="false"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm  not able to set the minRange and maxRange

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I limited date selection so that users only see the dates between two days:today and the coming day (assigned 10days later=it's a variable, you can change it as you want)
[assumed that today is 07/27/2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYXp8.jpg)
[thus 05/08/2017 would be 10days later~yay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KL1T.jpg)

first:
my code:

```
var myDate=new Date() ;
// Variable Declare＝today
var spanDay = myDate.getDate();
myDate.setDate(spanDay + 10);
//code above means you have assigned 10 days after myDate
```

then:

```
//in datepicker plugin

var $cells = $('#custom-cells');
$cells.data('datepicker');
$cells.datepicker({
        todayButton: new Date(),
        minDate: new Date(),

        maxDate:myDate,
        onRenderCell: function (date, cellType) {
            if (cellType == 'day') {
                var day = date.getDay(),
                    isDisabled = disabledDays.indexOf(day) != -1;
                return {
                    disabled: isDisabled
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$('#minMaxExample').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    minDate: new Date() // Now can select only dates, which goes after today
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use air datepicker's method selectDate() like this:

```
var datepicker = $('#my-elem').datepicker().data('datepicker');
datepicker.selectDate(startDate);
datepicker.selectDate(endDate);
```

Make sure your startDate and endDate is a javascript date, if is not, use

```
new Date(startDate)
```